# Retrieve the windows service uptime?

Tags: c#, windows, service, uptime

Is there is a way to get the start time of a windows service by code in C#?
Is there is a way to get the number of re-starts of the windows service in last 72 hours?

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.starttime.aspx) for the first question.

As for the second question, I think you would need to look at the Windows events to find how many time it started, unless you can change the code to log it somewhere.

Comment: That link gets you the start time of a particular process, not necessarily the OS. The "System Idle" and "System" processes have no start time that I can see in _Process Explorer_. The oldest process with a start time is "csrss.exe". Also be aware that with PCs that go into standby/hibernate if you get the original boot time it does not follow that the PC has been up for the whole time since then.

Comment: For some reason the word "the" in the title had me convinced the question was about the OS boot. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: That mean no way or API to get windows service uptime directely i must find its process then find starttime

Answer (score 1):

You can try to capture it from the Event Log. As far as I know when a service starts it hooks an entry to the event log.